# What capabilities does a Chromebook have that another OS running Chrome browser doesn’t

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

I’ve already purchased a Windows laptop for my daughter’s school. Last year we had to purchase a iPad. This next year they are insisting on a Chromebook.

My question is: Can I achieve the same effect running a Chrome browser on her Windows laptop? Alternatively is it possible to dual boot ChromeOS or run in a VM?

Comment: What is and is not possible entirely depends on the Chromebook.  The requirements to have a Chromebook with access to an iPad and a Windows laptop makes no sense.  Between the two devices there is NOTHING a chromebook can do that cannot be achieved another way

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I purchased the laptop and iPad for last year. This year they require a chromebook. I'm trying to figure out if I send her to school with chrome on her laptop will there be something she can't do.

Comment: I just answered that question.  Your question was clear enough.  The requirement of a Chromebook is silly.  Save your money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you say this:

> This next year they are insisting on a Chromebook.

And then you say this:

> My question is: Can I achieve the same effect running a Chrome browser
>   on her Windows laptop? Alternatively is it possible to dual boot
>   ChromeOS or run in a VM?

From my understanding of how Chrome works, a Windows laptop running Chrome would work just as well. But if the school is *insisting* on a Chromebook it could simply be because they want to eliminate the risk of rogue/infected Windows clients from being on their network. Requiring students use machines that are—for lack of a better term—“dumber” than a full-fledged Windows machine simplifies the life of the I.T. administrators at the school.

Now I am not saying that *any* Windows machine on *any* network is a risk, but judging by the pattern you describe—first Windows, then iPad and now Chromebook—it seems like the school’s I.T. department is trying to ensure that all clients on their network are as usable *and* not a potential security risk.

My guess is they had problems with the Windows machines so then decided iPads would work better. But then use of iPads was seen as too cumbersome, too limiting and too costly to some students, thus the new Chromebook “requirement.”

All that said, this all seems excessive and costly for all students and families involved. Also seems quite ham-fisted in implementation if you ask me.

So I would recommend that you—as a parent who has now purchased two machines for one student and now is being asked to purchase a 3rd—to push-back on the school requirements and simply ask *“You’re now asking me and other parents to purchase a 3rd piece of hardware for my child just for school. Why can’t she just use the Windows laptop with Chrome?”*

Comment: Or use Linux.  Or use the iPad.  Or use Winows with a ChromeOS VM.

Comment: So it sounds like there is no loss of functionality perhaps just simpler to administer and cheaper for the students than a regular laptop. I wonder then: if they do really insist it be a chromebook then would dual booting or a VM be an option? I've googled around and only found some downloads that seem to be unmaintained (circa 2013)